# For loops and too many if else how to test

Tags: java, arrays, performance, for-loop

I have a code which goes like this

```
List insert;
List update;
List delete
for(SomeObject someObj : someObjects){
    if(isNew){
        insert.add()
    }
    else if(isUpdate){
        update.add();
    }
    if(isDelete){
        delete.add()
    }
}

//call update insert delete functions
```

The problem is this code is untestable because the update insert delete are all void methods. 
My question is , should I consider iterating over the loop three times and then get the lists to test if the logic to filter each type of results is working? The cost is not that much since I am expecting <100 elements in the list.

Comment: you can check the length of the list to see if the list is updated

Comment: What do you mean by untestable? You can't unit test it or what? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Yes I cannot unit test it, or cannot completely unit test it. For eg if I change the code to something like getInsert() getUpdate() getDelete() I can test is better . The cost if of course that I will have to loop thrice. I just want to understand whether it is OK to do this or rather when should one chose to do this

Comment: `void` methods are testable.But more importantly, don't test multiple cases at one time; make specific cases to test.

Comment: If you are able to change the code. Why not creating three different methods for each case? I cannot thing about a case were a combination of the would be possible (e.g. `new` and `delete` at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

You can check

```
(sum of lists sizes after) == (sum of lists sizes before) + someObjects.size();
```

Comment: Yes, but if I change the code to something like getInsert() getUpdate() getDelete() I can test is better . The cost if of course that I will have to loop thrice. I just want to understand whether it is OK to do this or rather when should one chose to do this

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to be able to control the dependencies and access the state that this method acts upon.

Here is an example that illustrates that:

```
interface SomeDao {
    void add(SomeObject object);
    void update(SomeObject object);
    void delete(SomeObject object);
}

class SomeDaoStub implements SomeDao {
    @Override public void add(SomeObject object) {}
    @Override public void update(SomeObject object) {}
    @Override public void delete(SomeObject object) {}
}

class SomeObject {
    private final boolean isNew;
    private final boolean isUpdated;
    private final boolean isDeleted;
    SomeObject(boolean isNew, boolean isUpdated, boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isNew = isNew;
        this.isUpdated = isUpdated;
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }
    public boolean isUpdated() {
        return isUpdated;
    }
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }
}

public void doSomethingComplicatedWithListsInAForLoop(Iterable<SomeObject> someObjects, SomeDao dao) {
    for (SomeObject someObject : someObjects) {
        if (someObject.isNew()) {
            dao.add(someObject);
        } else if (someObject.isUpdated()) {
            dao.update(someObject);
        } else if (someObject.isDeleted()) {
            dao.delete(someObject);
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void itDeletesObjectsMarkedToBeDeleted() {
    final List<SomeObject> actualDeletedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    List<SomeObject> expectedDeletedObjects = Arrays.asList(
            new SomeObject(false, false, true),
            new SomeObject(false, false, true),
            new SomeObject(false, false, true)
    );
    SomeDao theDao = new SomeDaoStub() {
        @Override
        public void delete(SomeObject object) {
            actualDeletedObjects.add(object);
        }
    };
    doSomethingComplicatedWithListsInAForLoop(expectedDeletedObjects, theDao);
    assertEquals(expectedDeletedObjects, actualDeletedObjects);
}
```

The only reason that I can figure out what `doSomethingComplicatedWithListsInAForLoop` manipulated is because I can control its dependencies, namely, in this example, `SomeDao`.

It is likely that you are finding difficulty testing your method because it makes calls to state which you cannot *inject*.